# Why does [Co(NO2)6]4- ion have 3 unpaired electron as opposed to 1?

Tags: coordination-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry

Why does $\ce{[Co(NO2)6]^4-}$ ion have 3 unpaired electron as opposed to 1?

The book says that it has 3 unpaired electrons. I thought $\ce{NO2-}$ was a strong field ligand, making $\ce{Co^2+}$ a $\ce{d^7}$ low spin ion. Six electrons go in the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbital and 1 in the $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbital.

Please explain the bonding in this compound (preferably with a suitable MO diagram to go with it).

Comment: You can't predict which ligand is strong or weak, there are many factors which can change this.

Comment: An easier method - instead of getting tangled in the mess of strong vs weak field ligand - would be to make deductions based on the compound's calculated paramagnetic moments. Unfortunately, a simple Google search yields too [little information](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/463736). Perhaps, the chemists with more efficient database searches can help out here?

Answer (score 2):

According to Elliot, Hathaway & Slade (1966) cited by [this paper](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0567740880005535), Co(II) with nitrite ligands is low spin.

[image]

So maybe it is just a typo. For d7 low spin, you would expect one unpaired electron.